# Cross domain query *NON* SharePoint App senario

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I've been racking my brain about this and I am hoping others may help. I have two host-name site collections http://site1 and http://site2. These are both within the same SharePoint Web Application and I have **not** built any SharePoint (or Provider) hosted apps.

I've added a JS script to one of the pages within http://site1 that needs to access information from http://site2 over AJAX (right now I am using jQuery). When trying to do this am getting a Cross Domain error from the browser.

Has anyone had any luck trying to add a simple ASPX page into the SharePoint 'Pages' library, adding a JS snippet which hits a document library from another site collection, that is under a different domain?

Comment: Did you try `$.support.cors=true`?

Answer (score 0):

CORS is something strictly enforced by browsers. Querying across site collections is only possible if the two site collections share the same hostname/domain. (e.g. https://sharepoint.fqdn.local/sitecollection1 and https://sharepoint.fqdn.local/sitecollection2).